# Is Kegel exercise useful for combating erectile dysfunction?

Tags: erectile-dysfunction

[Healthline claims](http://www.healthline.com/health/erectile-dysfunction/exercises#Overview1) that doing Kegel exercise is very helpful in fixing erectile dysfunction:

> [Study from the University of the West](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1464-410X.2005.05690.x/pdf) in the U.K. found that pelvic
>   exercises helped 40 percent of men with ED regain normal erectile
>   function. They also helped an additional 33.5 percent significantly
>   improve erectile function. Additional research suggests pelvic muscle
>   training may be helpful for treating ED as well as other pelvic health
>   issues.

Although it cites a research paper, but I am still quite skeptical about it. If it works so well, then why doctors around the world are not recommending it as the first medication?

My question is, is Kegel exercise useful for combating erectile dysfunction? What is the current consensus of the medical community?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Per C Persu et.al. in [2009](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3019009/) regarding a practical update for treatment of erectile dysfunction,

> Pelvic floor exercises may reduce ED, although there is only limited evidence supporting that theory.

2. **Pelvic floor muscle exercises could be considered as a first-line approach for men seeking resolution of erectile dysfunction without pharmacological and surgical interventions** per Grace Dorey et.al. in [2004](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1324914/).

> Evidence has shown that pelvic floor muscle exercises are significantly effective for some men with erectile dysfunction. To obtain a benefit, pelvic floor muscle exercises should be properly taught and practised for at least 3 months. A maintenance programme may then be implemented for life. Not all men with erectile dysfunction may be suitable for pelvic floor muscle training. Those men with severe arteriogenic and neurological causes may well not benefit.